# Eclipse 2022-06 java.security.AccessControlException state.dat/.markers write

Tags: java, eclipse, accesscontrolexception

I have a weird problem after updateing to Eclipse 2022-06. I'm running it on Windows 10 under java.version=17.0.3 java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc.
When I exit my (newly created) workspace after changing some system properties or project content, I get an error message:

> Problems occurred while trying to save the state of the workbench.

**java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "D:\xxxxxx.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\MyProject\org.eclipse.jdt.core\state.dat" "write")**

*or*

**java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" ""D:\xxxxxx.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\MyProject.markers" "write")**

at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:485)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1068)
at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:416)
at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:847)
at ro.sync.security.manager.SandboxSecurityManager.checkWrite(SandboxSecurityManager.java:188)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:223)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:184)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.createOutputStream(JavaModelManager.java:4387)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.saveBuiltState(JavaModelManager.java:4341)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.saveState(JavaModelManager.java:4323)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.lambda$1(JavaModelManager.java:4699)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Nodes$CollectorTask.doLeaf(Nodes.java:2183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Nodes$CollectorTask$OfRef.doLeaf(Nodes.java:2193)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:327)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:754)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:686)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Nodes.collect(Nodes.java:328)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.evaluateToNode(ReferencePipeline.java:111)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:570)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.lambda$0(JavaModelManager.java:4704)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1428)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)

I even tried to add my project path to the java.policy file ->
**permission java.io.FilePermission "D:\xxxxxx-", "write"**

but that didn't help.

Is this a known issue? Any suggestions how I can resolve the problem?

Thanx
Thomas

Comment: Do you get the same issue when running Eclipse with a different Java VM? If not, did you read the [release notes](https://docs.azul.com/core/zulu-openjdk/release-notes.html) whether it's a known issue?

Comment: I had the same problem with JDK 11 - so I guess this is an eclipse related problem.

Comment: Does your user fully own and have write access to the entire workspace folder and its contents?

Comment: Yes. I also started eclipse as administrator - same problem. I also moved the complete project folder under my Windows User folder - same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had oXygen 23.1 (to be clear - it's an older version not recomended for eclipse 2022-06) installed that seems to cause the problem. After uninstalling this version everything works fine.